# Is it possible to borrow different parts of self with different mutability statically?

Tags: rust

I am designing some struct with a prepare-commit pattern in rust, which mostly looks like this after simplified:

```rust
struct Data {
    a: usize,
}

struct Adder<'a> {
    data: &'a mut Data,
    added: usize,
}

struct Holder<'a> {
    data: &'a Data,
}

impl<'a> Adder<'a> {
    fn add_once(&mut self) {
        // Needs added to be mut, but not data
        self.added = self.added + self.data.a;
    }
    fn commit(&mut self) {
        // Needs data to be mut, but not added
        self.data.a = self.added;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut d = Data { a: 1 };
    let h = Holder { data: &d };
    let mut ad = Adder {
        data: &mut d,
        added: 0,
    };
    ad.add_once();
    ad.add_once();
    println!("{}", h.data.a); // Cannot borrow here
    ad.commit();
    println!("{}", ad.data.a);
}
```

This snippet does not compile. The problem with the code snippet is that since `Adder` is borrowing `data` as mutable, upon the creation of `Adder` struct, all other immutable borrows (e.g.`Holder` here) could not live past. However, the `add_once` calls really do not need to borrow `data` mutably, only `commit` does that. Ideally there should be some way in rust to let the compiler know that `add_once` only needs `added` as mutable but not `data`, so that `Holder` could live past `add_once` calls but not `commit` call.

I do know two possible current solutions to this, however I think they both have drawbacks:

1. I could wrap fields of `Adder` in `RefCell` and borrow entire `Adder` immutably, only borrows mutably when needed. The problem with this approach is that `RefCell` checks borrowing dynamically, when in this case it really does not need to be that way since all lifetime bounds should be known at compile time, just different parts of a struct could have different bounds.
2. I could do `unsafe` blocks to convert references to raw pointers and do whatever I want. However as far as I think about it I could not find a way to do it without disable all borrow checks altogether (I don't really know how to do unsafe rust properly). And I want a borrow check so that if `Holder` lives past `commit` the compiler would still give a proper borrow error

So summary of questions:

- Is there a static and safe way in rust to borrow different parts of self, with different mutability?
- If not, is there a unsafe boilerplate to do so, still ensuring the proper borrow check as described above? (and if there is an existing crate for this)
- What is the best practice in general for these situations?
- Is there any RFC addressing this issue from rust language level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a static and safe way in rust to borrow different parts of self, with different mutability?

No.

> If not, is there a unsafe boilerplate to do so, still ensuring the proper borrow check as described above? (and if there is an existing crate for this)

You can use `unsafe` for that, but it will require you to work with raw pointers only. You may be able to encapsulate it in a safe API, but it's unlikely that inside the code you'll have proper automatic verification. For this reason I also don't believe there is a crate for that, at least I don't know one.

> What is the best practice in general for these situations?

It depends.

I would use `RefCell` (or other interior mutability primitives such as `Cell` - note that if you can use `Cell` it is actually zero-cost) for that generally, and use unsafe code if profiling shows a bottleneck. However, this kind of issues many times arises from improper API design. So first I'll see if I can redesign my API so the problem will not exist.

> Is there any RFC addressing this issue from rust language level?

Not today, and I think it is very unlikely in the future.

There was something similar suggested while working on [two phase borrows](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/borrow_check/two_phase_borrows.html): https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/49434. The idea was that any mutable reference will start as shared and only "upgrade" when it is actually used. In can be extended to "upgrade" only when a mutable reference is actually required, and this is basically what you propose.

However, the effect of two-phase borrows is completely local. For your code to work, we will have to need some way to represent time-aware mutable reference in a type. I don't see that happening.

In addition, [two-phase borrows work poorly with Stacked Borrows](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/56254). [@RalfJung ended up with just using raw pointers when two phase borrows are involved](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/96268#issuecomment-1105261537). Using them for everything will probably mean poor optimization opportunities (although maybe future models, or even Stacked Borrows itself, will find a way to handle that).

Comment: I think there was some commotion around partial self borrows semi recently, can't find the discussion right nowm

Comment: @IvanC Yes, you're referring to @nikomatsakis [post about view types](https://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2021/11/05/view-types/) and the following discussions. But this was not about this situation; it was about borrowing `self` partially in methods but the struct still holds the reference, and you also need to access it, just immutably.